# How not to overlap line in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

**The text is overlapping my line.**
*How can I solve this problem?*

> I need my line to touch the circle. It's in a LimitedBox It will be a
> process indicator

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 40.0,
      height: 40.0,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xffEFF2FA),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          width: 1,
          color: const Color(0xff1F46A0),
        ),
      ),
      child: const Text(
        '1',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xff000000),
          fontFamily: 'Inter',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 4,
    ),
    const Text(
      'Basic infos',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xff000000),
        fontFamily: 'Inter',
        fontSize: 11,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
  child: Container(
    height: 1,
    width: 50.0,
    color: const Color(0xff3D3D3D),
  ),
)
```

What happened

[image]

What I was trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Try setting the padding of the circle container to zero. `EdgeInsets.zero`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have text and numbers in the same `Column`, size expands based on text.
Try with following code..

```dart
class StepsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  StepsWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final steps = ['Basic Infos', 'Place of Living', 'ID', 'Verification', 'Done'];
  final int current = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++)
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: (i != 0)
                        ? Container(
                            height: 1,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: const Color(0xff3D3D3D),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox(),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 40.0,
                    height: 40.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xffEFF2FA),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: i<current? const Color(0xff1F46A0):  const Color(0xffEFF2FA),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '${i + 1}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff000000),
                        fontFamily: 'Inter',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: i != steps.length - 1
                        ? Container(
                            height: 1,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            color: const Color(0xff3D3D3D),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 4,
              ),
              Text(
                steps[i],
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff000000),
                  fontFamily: 'Inter',
                  fontSize: 11,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    ]);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps..

For a guide, pass `current` that indicates how many steps highlighted.